# Reinstalling g++ and get bus error

Tags: c++, g++, reinstall

Today I removed the g++ package with the commands:

```
sudo apt remove g++
sudo apt purge g++
```

So, I reinstalled it with:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt install build-essential
```

After the installation proccess, I checked for the g++ version with

```
g++ --version
```

And I get the error

```
Bus error(core dumped)
```

Even when I simple write

```
g++
```

in the terminal, I get the same error.

I need to use a C++ compiler for work. What can I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

As asked, my Ubuntu version is 18.04

```
type -a g++
```

Returned

```
g++ is /usr/bin/g++

realpath $(which g++)
```

Returned

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7
```

And

```
dpkg -l | grep 'g++'
```

Returned

```
ii  g++                                              4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3                               amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-6                                            6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04                             amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-7                                            7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                           amd64        GNU C++ compiler
```

Comment: `g++` on Ubuntu is just a dependency package - please [edit] your question to include your Ubuntu version and outputs of `type -a g++`, `realpath $(which g++)` and `dpkg -l | grep 'g++'`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your commentary! I've edited the post.

Comment: Hmm... so I don't see anything out of the ordinary there - you could try reinstalling the `g++-7` package - if that doesn't help I'd suspect something is messed up with one or more of the libraries that it links to

Comment: @steeldriver perfect! I'll try to reinstall g++. Thanks a lot!